# Send Time Optimization Expected Behavior With Wait Activities

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, einstein

I have a journey with the following flow:

1. Enter Journey at 10am
2. Email 1 Sent
3. 7 Day Wait Activity
4. 24hr STO Activity
5. Email 2 Sent
6. 7 Day Wait Activity
7. 24hr STO Activity
8. Email 3 Sent

The contact in question receives Email 1 at 10am on Day 1. If the contact's personalized send time is 9am wouldn't they receive Email 2 at 9am on Day 9? I'm trying to figure out if a 24hr sto activity has the potential to extend a journey / wait times depending on the contact's personalized send time. Documentation isn't too clear on this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFMC Support confirmed that yes, it would be possible for an STO activity to extend the length of a journey depending on the journey's setup. In my case described above it could potentially add on an additional day or two.

If entering a contact to an email activity at the same time is the desired outcome using the 'extend wait time...' option in the wait time activity configuration can help with this.